# can someone help me with my osmroid RoadManger code?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

i followed the tutorial from https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1 all worked well until i added the RoadManager to add a polyline between two points, android studio did not report any error but with my genymotion emulator he told me unfortunately myapp has stopped while i tried osmbonuspack master code it work well into my emulator 
please help me here my project 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/9ssvn5g0t9m243m/osmcarte.rar

My log level error

```
04-11 17:32:14.853 3008-3008/com.osmdroid.android.osmdroidmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.osmdroid.android.osmdroidmap/com.osmdroid.android.osmdroidmap.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
                                                                                at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
                                                                                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                                                                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:184)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:153)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:95)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
                                                                                at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
                                                                                at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.utils.HttpConnection.doGet(HttpConnection.java:62)
                                                                                at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.utils.BonusPackHelper.requestStringFromUrl(BonusPackHelper.java:74)
                                                                                at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.OSRMRoadManager.getRoads(OSRMRoadManager.java:178)
                                                                                at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.OSRMRoadManager.getRoad(OSRMRoadManager.java:243)
                                                                                at com.osmdroid.android.osmdroidmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your question is way to broad, please give specific errors and stacktraces of the error. You said its crashing so look in android studio and find the error the paste it here

Comment: thanks for your reply i edited my post